# I am unable to figure out how to create a multiple step code with bivariate normal distribution

Tags: r

Consider the following method to generate a random sample from a bivariate normal distribution. First, generate random number x, y independently from the standard normal and form a pair (x, y)^'; second, compute the Choleski’s factorization, where ρ is some constant takes value in (−1, 1) and R is an upper triangle matrix; third, compute a new pair The resulting new pair then has a bivariate normal distribution with correlation coefficient ρ. then generate 100 pairs of random vectors with ρ = −0.8, 0.5, 0.8, respectively; then ) construct a scatter plot of y vs x for each of the three cases. 
 for each of the three cases, compute the sample mean, sample variance of x and y respectively, and the sample correlation between x and y

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please show any code you've already written to solve this, and try to explain specifically where you're stuck with it.

Comment: This is a nice exercise and I encourage you to spend some time on a coding solution (you should be able to find plenty of related material through a google search). I'm happy to help if/when you get stuck but at the moment this is just a homework dump.

Answer (score 1):

**Some critical comments first:**

1. This is a nice exercise, and I *strongly* encourage you to spend some time researching coding implementations. You can find plenty of relevant material on the web.
2. As far as homework questions are concerned, we generally expect you to adhere to some [key rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions); in a nutshell, we expect you to demonstrate a genuine attempt at solving the problem yourself. You should share your code attempt and clearly indicate where you got stuck. Nobody around here likes ["gimmeh teh codez" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question).

With these things out of the way, here are some code "ideas" that should help you with properly addressing your homework. This is **not a full solution**, because as explained above and in the comments, this is not how SO works.

---

#### Background

In the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) we can decompose the positive definite variance-covariance matrix `Sigma` as `Sigma = R R^T` for some lower triangular matrix `R`. The vector `X = mu + R Z` then has a multivariate normal distribution, where

- `Z` is a vector `(Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n)` of `n` independent standard normal variables,
- `R` is the `r x n` lower triangular matrix linked to the variance-covariance matrix through the Cholesky decomposition, and
- `mu` is the vector `(mu_1, mu_2, ..., mu_r)` of means.

For the *bivariate* standard normal case the variance-covariance matrix is simply a `2 x 2` matrix with unit diagonal and `rho` on the off-diagonal elements.

#### R code

We can define a function `bvsigma` that returns the bivariate variance-covariance matrix for a given correlation coefficient `rho` and variances `sigma_1` and `sigma_2`.

```
bvsigma <- function(rho = 0.8, sigma_1 = 1, sigma_2 = 1)
    matrix(c(sigma_1^2, rho * sigma_1 * sigma_2, rho * sigma_1 * sigma_2, sigma_2^2), ncol = 2)
```

For a standard bivariate normal distribution with `rho = 0.8` we have

```
sigma <- bvsigma(rho = 0.8)
sigma
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  0.8
#[2,]  0.8  1.0
```

The lower triangular matrix is then

```
R <- t(chol(sigma))
R
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.8  0.6
```

We confirm that indeed `R R^T` recovers the variance-covariance matrix

```
R %*% t(R)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  1.0  0.8
#[2,]  0.8  1.0
```

We can now put all the pieces together and define a function `rbvnorm` that returns `n` samples from a bivariate standard normal with variance-covariance matrix `sigma`

```
rbvnorm <- function(n, sigma) {
    R <- t(chol(sigma))
    t(do.call(cbind, replicate(n, {
        Z <- rnorm(2)
        R %*% Z
    }, simplify = FALSE)))}
```

Let's draw `n = 1000` samples from a bivariate standard normal distribution with `rho = 0.8` and plot the data

```
set.seed(2018)
mat <- rbvnorm(1000, bvsigma(rho = 0.8))

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = as.data.frame(mat), aes(V1, V2)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]